# forum category problem

Tags: php, mysqli

i have a forum and in that forum people can create a thread in a category they chose, but i wanna check if the category exists but i dont know how to, because know if i type another category number in the URL i still see the page.

here is my code

```
    $kategoriID = $_GET['kategoriID'];

if(!isset($overskrift) || !isset($indhold) || !isset($fejl))
{
 $overskrift = "";
 $indhold    = "";
 $fejl   = false;


}#Lukker if isset overskrift,indhold


 if(isset($kategoriID))
 {

   #tjek om kategori findes
  $mysql = connect();
        $stmt = $mysql->prepare("SELECT count(fk_forum_kategori) As t_id FROM forum_traad WHERE fk_forum_kategori = '$kategoriID'") or die($mysql->error);
        $stmt->bind_result($t_id);
        $stmt->execute() or die($mysql->error);
  $stmt->fetch();

  if($t_id <= 0)
  {
   echo $t_id;
   $fejl == true;
   echo "<br>HEj med dig!";
   exit();
  } 
 }#Lukker isset







if(isset($_POST['send'])) {

 $kategoriID = $_GET['kategoriID'];
 $overskrift = htmlspecialchars($_POST['overskrift']);
 $indhold    = htmlspecialchars($_POST['indhold']);
 $godkendt   = "ja";

 if($fejl == true)
 {
  $error = "Denne kategori findes ikke"; 
 } elseif(empty($overskrift) || empty($indhold)) {
  $error = "Alle felter skal udfyldes";
 } else {
  $mysql = connect();
  $stmt = $mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO forum_traad (overskrift, indhold, fk_forum_kategori, brugernavn, dato, godkendt) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)") or die($mysql->error);
  $stmt->bind_param('ssisis', $overskrift, $indhold, $kategoriID, $_SESSION['username'], $dato, $godkendt) or die($mysql->error);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->close();

  $traadID = mysqli_insert_id($mysql);

  header("location: forum.traad.php?traadID=$traadID&kategoriID=$kategoriID");
 }#Lukker else




}#Lukker isset send
```

Comment: +1, not sure why this was voted down, seems like a reasonable question. However, this is difficult for me, as I don't understand any of the variable names.

Comment: Watch out for SQL Injection attacks on your "kategoriID", if the user can set that.

http://cwe.mitre.org/top25/#CWE-89

Comment: @David, watch out for anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some logic errors. I'm kind of guessing how the script works because I don't know what the variable names mean (they're in Swedish?). Here're my thoughts:

```
$kategoriID = $_GET['kategoriID'];

if(!isset($overskrift) || !isset($indhold) || !isset($fejl))
{
 $overskrift = "";
 $indhold    = "";
 $fejl       = false;
}
```

If *any* of three variables aren't set, set them **all** to their default values. My guess is that this is your problem right here, one of the three isn't ever set so you're always using defaults.

```
if(isset($kategoriID))
{
  $mysql = connect(); // let's assume this works
  $stmt = $mysql->prepare("SELECT count(fk_forum_kategori) As t_id FROM forum_traad WHERE fk_forum_kategori = '$kategoriID'") or die($mysql->error);
```

Select the number of times *each row* that matches your category id exists. This will always be 1. I recommend `SELECT COUNT(*) AS`times`FROM`forum_traad`WHERE`fk_forum_kategori`= '$kategoriID'` (incidentally, if you're doing a prepared statement, you would normally do `$mysql->prepare("SELECT ... WHERE id = ?"); $mysql->bind_param('d', $id);`).

```
  $stmt->bind_result($t_id);
  $stmt->execute() or die($mysql->error);
  $stmt->fetch();

  if($t_id <= 0)
  {
    echo $t_id;
    $fejl == true;
    echo "<br>HEj med dig!";
    exit();
  }
}
```

If there are no threads for the given category, stop execution of the script.

```
if(isset($_POST['send']))
{
  $kategoriID = $_GET['kategoriID'];
  $overskrift = htmlspecialchars($_POST['overskrift']);
  $indhold    = htmlspecialchars($_POST['indhold']);
  $godkendt   = "ja";

  if($fejl == true)
  {
    $error = "Denne kategori findes ikke"; 
  }
  elseif (empty($overskrift) || empty($indhold))
  {
    $error = "Alle felter skal udfyldes";
  }
  else
  {
```

The user has submitted their thread. First, check if they are missing anything and if so set up a useful error message. If everything is ok:

```
    $mysql = connect();
    $stmt = $mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO forum_traad (overskrift, indhold, fk_forum_kategori, brugernavn, dato, godkendt) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)") or die($mysql->error);
    $stmt->bind_param('ssisis', $overskrift, $indhold, $kategoriID, $_SESSION['username'], $dato, $godkendt) or die($mysql->error);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
```

Insert the new thread into your database and close your connection.

```
    $traadID = mysqli_insert_id($mysql);

    header("location: forum.traad.php?traadID=$traadID&kategoriID=$kategoriID");
  }
}
```

Redirect the user to their new thread. But what, you're trying to get the latest insert id *from a closed connection*.

So, given all this I think you can simply this a lot by verifying that they're using a valid category id, which I'm assuming is in another database, `fk_forum_kategori` being a foreign key to that table. Here's what I'd do:

```
$mysqli = connect();

function isValidCategory($id) {
  $statement = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `id` = ?");
  $statement->bind_params("i", $mysqli->real_escape_string($id));
  $statement->execute();
  $num_rows = $statement->num_rows;
  $statement->close();
  if ($num_rows > 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
  // or:
  // return ($statement->num_rows > 0);
  // or even, if you're happy with 0 being converted to false and everything else to true:
  // return $statement->num_rows;
}

if (isValidCategory($_GET['category_id']) {
  if (is_empty($_POST['title']) {
    print "Missing title. Please go back and try again.";
    return false;
  }
  if (is_empty($_POST['content']) {
    print "Missing content. Please go back and try again.";
    return false;
  }


  $statement = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `threads` (`title`, `content`, `author`, `category_id`, `created`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())");
  $statement->bind_params("sssi",
    $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['title']),
    $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['content']),
    $mysqli->real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']),
    $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['category_id']),
  );
  $statement->execute();
  $statement->close();

  if ($thread_id = $mysqli->insert_id()) {
    header("Location: view_thread.php?thread_id=$thread_id");
  } else {
    print "Sorry, we were unable to create your thread. Please go back and try again later.";
  }
} else {
  print "Invalid category idea. Please go back and try again.";
}
```

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT count(fk_forum_kategori) As t_id
```

Probably isn't what you want here. Using count() will return the number of rows that match the criteria following it in your SQL query, so it's likely to always show you category number 1 (since each category number will only appear once in the database).

You will probably want something like this instead:

```
"SELECT fk_forum_kategori FROM forum_traad WHERE fk_forum_kategori = '$kategoriID'"
```

Comment: hollsk how i then echo it so i can test if it exists?

Comment: You would use the bind_request() function for that (like you're already using) - the contents of fk_forum_kategori should be inside the $t_id variable just as before. If you need to output more columns then add them to the SQL query separated with commas, and then add more variables to bind_request() also comma separated, in the same order as your columns. Hope this helps.